# Add another primary key to table in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I want to add another primary key to a table in mysql.
I use phpmyadmin to communicate with mysql server.
When I click the primary icon for the desired field it gives me this error:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

**Edited:**

here's the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `files` DROP PRIMARY KEY ,ADD PRIMARY KEY ( `file_type` )
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you need one more primary key?

Comment: You can only have one primary key (although it may be a composite of several columns) but if you give a concrete example of what you want to achieve there may be another solution.

Comment: @Shakti: I need the combination of three columns to avoid some duplicated records.

Comment: @Alvaro: Ok,I delete the Drop primary key phrase from query,but it gives this error: ' Multiple primary key defined'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name "primary" key says, there may be only one of that (ref: Highlander).

What you might want to try is a UNIQUE KEY, that acts just like a primary for most purpouses. Auto_increment doesn't seem to fulfill any purpouse if used a second time - what'ts the point of two fields carrying exactly the same information?

Answer (score 3):

I believe in your case, what you need is a composite key.  I do not know your table structure, but here is a general example taken from [here](http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip241027/i02create.xml),

```
CREATE TABLE track(
  album CHAR(10),
  disk INTEGER,
  posn INTEGER,
  song VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (album, disk, posn)
)
```

In this case, there is a combination of 3 columns which avoid the duplicate records as you require.  Please let me know if I have any mistakes in understanding your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it, I think:

the auto_increment column must be key.

So use this query first:

```
ALTER TABLE 'files' CHANGE 'id' 'id' INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT  NULL;
```

this will remove the auto_increment.

Also, I recommend the Uniqe key as suggested by other answer. I believe there should always (almost) be an Id column in each table.

Answer (score 0):

We can Give Primary Key only once for a table. You can prefer UNIQUE KEY to prevent duplicate records

> ALTER TABLE Persons
>   ADD UNIQUE (P_Id)

Answer (score -1):

You can mark all the fields you want as primary keys, including the existing one. The system internally will drop the existing one and will set all you marked.